# Can followers (templar, enchantress, scoundrel) die?

Tags: diablo-iii

They are [supposed](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Followers) to leave battle when they are low on health, but what qualifies as low health, or can they TP out? Will they die if they're trapped in a mob and can't escape? If so, what happens? Are there any other circumstances in which they will die? How long are they gone?  Will they be in town if they've gone away, and can you go back to town to pick them up, or must you wait either way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they don't die. If they go to 0 health, they disappear from the battle and reappear sometime later (even if the same fight is still going on).

It was easiest to test this with the skeleton king. My templar "died" a couple of times and came back 30 seconds or something like that later (Although that number is just an estimate, I haven't measured).

Comment: NOTE: Blizzard has released the follow information: "Followers are not very useful in high levels of difficulty (like hell and inferno)" this is because, in those levels, you shouldn't be playing alone. NOTE2: If you are in a party you can't have your follower (neither your partners can) and you can't re-hire them. Note3: When you leave a group and starts a solo adventure, you need to re-hire your specific follower, they stay in the city near your Blacksmith/town-portal (this is in New Tristan).

Comment: @Michel That seems to contradict the repeated statements by Blizzard that the game is designed to be soloable at all difficulty levels. Do you have a link to the source of that statement?

Comment: @Beofett Take a look [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0F2wPZWdYk) btw,can **YOU** provide this statement?

Comment: @Michel That video says nothing about group vs. solo. It's just an explanation of how hard Inferno will be (and Blizzard claims that they expect it to be months before *anyone* can "beat" Inferno, regardless of team or solo).  As for my claim, here's the [main source](http://www.diablofans.com/news/1174-unlock-6-the-order-jay-wilson-qas-zarhym-on-pvp-blue-posts/).  Its from an interview he did in Korea (translated into English).

Comment: Also, [this](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3161501347).  Perhaps you are basing your comments on their original announcement, since it seems they changed their mind about follower viability at high level.

Comment: @Beofett Yeap. As in the video, they say "You and your group", when you are in a group you can't have a follower with you. PS: Sorry for the fast comments, lunch time and playing LoL at same time.

Comment: @Michel There was one comment, saying "your group really has to work together".  This doesn't mean "you have to be in a group".  It means "you can't go off on your own and expect to be able to solo when in a multiplayer game on Inferno", which is something that Blizzard has explicitly stated elsewhere.