# What happens when your follower dies?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can followers (templar, enchantress, scoundrel) die?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64451/can-followers-templar-enchantress-scoundrel-die)

Much like my former question involving player death, I am curious as to how death works yet again, but this time the focus is on Followers, not players.

In the previous installments of Diablo death worked differently depending on the game. How, in Diablo 3, does death work upon your follower? Does he\she respawn? If so where? Does it cost money to bring them back? Ect.

Comment: Yup its a dupe. My D3 searching skills are failing me hard, 2nd time in two days. Bah. (I'm legitimatly searching before posting, but somehow not finding these other questions) VTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They kneel down for a small period of time, then stand back up and continue fighting.  There's no permanent penalty for a follower dying.